# ajax in rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have ajax code in rails 3 that is not responding in contoller.. here the code goes...

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

 <script type="text/javascript">    
   function fetching(){
     var data=document.getElementById('parent_type').value
     if(data){
       req = new Ajax.Request('/registrations/select_type/1', {
         method: 'get',
         parameters: { data : data},
         onComplete: function(transport) {
           processReqChange(transport);
         }
       }); // end ajax req
     }          
   }
 </script>
```

and in registration controller--

```
def select_type
  raise "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii".inspect
  render :js =>"document.getElementById('parent_lname').value='jyothi';"
end
```

here it is not raising "hiiii" it means ajax request is not calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your registrations controller you should have a respond_to block

```
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :js =>"document.getElementById('parent_lname').value='jyothi';"}
   end
```

for further reading

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to

Comment: it is not at all calling the method "select_type".. from ajax request.. that is the problem i am facing

Comment: try adding the format to the end of your url in the ajax call (.html). Can you also check your logs for any erors then look in your browser console to see if it is raising any errors.